# how to enable the RadioButtonList while retriving from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am using a RadioButtonList,Active and InActive are list items.
I didt specify any values to the list items and i am using this code for inserting the value to the database, every time its taking the true value only..

```
staffMaster.IsActive = ui_rblIsActive.Enabled == true ? true : false;
```

staffMaster is a VO object which i created in the WCF layer..

while retriving from database i ve tried this code specified below, for enabling radio button, but its not showing as enabled.. table has only true values..

```
ui_rblIsActive.Enabled =Convert.ToBoolean(ui_gridView.SelectedRow.Cells[13].Text);
```

What mistake i have done here???? what i ve to do, to insert & retrive data properly..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ui_rblIsActive.Enabled`  is just telling you whether the control is enabled, not what if anything is selected.  You want to use ui_rblIsActive.SelectedValue instead.  If you did not privde any value you will get the text of the radio button label.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information, with the info you provided, I guess you should use rbl's SelectedItem.(Text|Value) property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx